# Are there a better practice to hold monster images than in the timeline *flash*

Tags: flash, bitmap

Let's say I have some monsters in my game and they need to be generated randomly. They need to have some graphics and I am not sure what's the best way to do so. I have read a book where the writer used the time line to hold different images for cards for instance. The card class would then set it's content from the time line. In my opinion this really sounds like hard coding. Aren't there any better solutions to this like holding the images in an array or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use an xml file to reference all your monsters these can be images or swfs it doesn't matter, give them a bunch of ids, then use [bulkloader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/) to load them all in. You can then get hold of them using their ids in bulkloader, check it out.